# Are there finitely-presented astral monoids?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

We say a semigroup $S$ is *$k$-astral* if there exists a finite set $F \subset S$ such that
whenever $s_1, s_2, ..., s_k \in S$ there exists $s \in S$ such that $\forall i: s_i \in sF$. Say $S$ is *astral* if it is $k$-astral
for all $k$.

I'm interested in general information about this definition: does it have an existing name, has it been studied, connections to other notions; you can also suggest a better name if you have one. Some concrete questions

> Is there an infinite finitely-presented astral monoid/semigroup?

and (interpret as you wish)

> Do infinite finitely-generated astral monoids/semigroups "occur in nature"?

I don't have a particular application, just curiosity, this seems like a very strange property so I'd like to know more about it. (This did arise from a research problem, but I already found another way around it.)

Some observations below.

Obviously every monoid is $1$-astral (pick $F = \{1_S\}$), and in general a semigroup is $1$-astral if and only if there is a finite set $F \subset S$
such that $SF = S$. If to every finite $F \subset S$ we associate the *Cayley graph* with nodes $S$ and directed edges $\{(s, sf) \;|\; f \in F\}$
(no connectedness assumption), then  by fixing $s_1$ and changing $s_2$, we see easily that if a semigroup is $k$-astral for $k \geq 2$ then the
in-degrees of all nodes in some Cayley graph are infinite.

A semigroup is $k$-astral if in its Cayley graph, every $k$-tuple of elements forms the
leaves of a (not necessarily induced) directed star graph (directed $K_{1,k}$): $s$ will be the center of the star and $s_i = sf_i$ for some choices $f_i \in F$.
Directly from the definition you only obtain this for possibly degenerate stars (that is, you may have $s = s_i$ for some $i$), but if $S$ is infinite and
$k \geq 2$, it is easy to show that if $F$ satisfies $k$-astrality then $F^2$ satisfies $k$-astrality with non-degenerate directed stars.
(The fact all tuples are the points of stars is why I call these astral, it was a nice and short name and didn't seem to be in use.)

If $S$ is a group, $2$-astrality would mean that you can find for any two elements $s_1, s_2$ some $s \in S$ such that $s_1$ and $s_2$
are at a uniformly bounded distance from $s$ in the path metric w.r.t. $F \cup F^{-1}$. This is clearly impossible unless $G$ is locally finite. Thus, no
infinite finitely-generated group is $k$-astral for any $k \geq 2$.

Finitely-generated astral monoids do exist. Let $A$ be a finite alphabet. Write $A^*$ for the free monoid over $A$ consisting of (possibly empty) words. Write $|w|$ for the length of a word. Say a set of words $C \in A^*$ *has no overlaps* if $uv, vw \in C$ implies $|v| = 0$ or $uv = vw$.

> Lemma. Let $C \subset A^*$ have no overlaps and $\phi : C \to A^*$ satisfies $|\phi(w)| < |w|$ for all $w \in C$. Consider the monoid presentation
>   $M_\phi = \langle A \;|\; \forall w \in C: \phi(w) \approx w \rangle$. If $a \in A$ and $a^* \cap C = \emptyset$ then $M_\phi$ is infinite.

Proof. The system of rewrite rules $uvw \rightarrow u\phi(v)w$ is locally confluent because $C$ has no overlaps. and terminating because the rule makes words shorter.
Newman's lemma says that it is confluent and that its repeated application puts elements in a unique normal form. Under the assumption on $C$, the normal form of
$a^n$ is $a^n$, so $M_\phi$ is infinite.

> Proposition. There exists an infinite finitely-generated astral monoid.

Proof. Let $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and for each tuple $(w_1, ..., w_k) \in (A^*)^k$ pick (distinct) $n > \max_i |w_i|$, let $ab^nc^id \in C$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k$ and define $\phi(ab^nc^id) = w_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k$. By the previous lemma, $M_\phi$ is infinite, and it is clearly astral: given $k$, pick
$F = \{c^id \;|\; 1 \leq i \leq k\}$; then given $w_1, ..., w_k$ we have $\phi(ab^nc^id) = w_i$ for all $i$, so $m = ab^n$ satisfies $mF \supset \{w_1,...,w_k\}$.

Comment: No infinite group at all is 2-astral. Indeed let $F$ be any finite subset. Then the set of $g$ such that $\{1,g\}\subset sF$ for some $s$ is finite: indeed if $1=su$ and $g=sv$ for some $s$ and $u,v\in F$, then $g=u^{-1}v\in F^{-1}F$. This also holds in left-cancelative monoids, since $1=su$ yields $s=sus$, hence $1=us$ and the same argument works with $F^{-1}$ defined as the set of inverses of invertible elements of $F$.

Comment: True. I guess in both cases, in-degrees are finite in Cayley graphs.

Comment: But the Cayley graph point of view artificially restricts the argument to finitely generated groups/monoids. My comment makes no such assumption and in particular applies to locally finite groups.

Comment: Did you notive I used a nonstandard definition where connectedness is not assumed? Maybe I'm missing some subtle point, I usually work only with f.g. groups.

Comment: Indeed when you say is $k$-astral if in its Cayley graph", you mean "if for some finite subset $F$, the Cayley graph of $(S,F)$ satisfies..." OK, in general if $S$ is 2-astral your argument shows that the Cayley graph of $(S,F)$ is connected as well, doesn't it? In the group case it yields the conclusion that $F$ generates the group, and hence yields the finite (not only locally finite) conclusion.

Comment: Yes, I was satisfied with them being locally finite because I was thinking about f.g., but you're right that this is artificial.

Comment: I haven’t it  before. It seems to me F will have to have an element with infinitely many left inverses which is pretty strong.